# What are the best practices to manage and move Docker containers?

Tags: docker, cloud

We are evaluating Docker to use for our application,so really like to know the following questions:

What are the best practices to move docker images and container between different machine? 
Also how to manage containers and images in production environment across different regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all Docker architecture has a push pull mechanism using Registry(which may be private or public(like docker Hub).

1) Answer to your first Question- **Moving Docker images and container between machines?**

You can create tar file of images or container and then move the tar file between your machines.

Check using **docker ps -a**,then based on your requirement use any one of the following:

**$ docker ps -a**

CONTAINER ID    IMAGE           COMMAND      CREATED          STATUS
68d9619a7a91    ubuntu:14.04    "/bin/bash" 10 seconds ago    Exited

*For Container  move - Use docker export and import:*

---

**$ docker export 68d9619a7a91  > ubuntu-container.tar**

**$ docker import - update < ubuntu-container.tar**

*For  Image move -- Use docker save and load:*

---

**$ docker images**

**$ docker save -o image.tar**

**$ docker load < image.tar**

2) Second question- Managing containers in production environment?

**a)** It is better to have your own private registry managing all the images that you need for your containers. Suppose you have a dedicated node as Docker registry where all your docker images will stay.Now you can push your changes or updates of the images to the registry and then accordingly pull this images from this registry to your machine that will run the containers from ths images.

**b)** Another great way of managing images/container across cluster and  different cloud provider is to use a **[Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/)**(open sourced by Google). Although we have not implemented Kubernetes,but just started looking into its documentation,and it looks very promising if you are using docker containers and cloud.

Comment: i would caution against an image move.  if you need the image on another machine have it build your Dockerfile as part of your CI or deployment process.  that way it can tag it and manage it automatically.  automate always.

Comment: I also agree that in production you should never use tar move and use your images. Thats why i mentioned to maintain a private registry where all your latest images build from DockerFile would be kept and you just need to pull from your running machine...  You can use docker file with CI to build images on your running instances, but that wont reuse the images. But even using CI automation you have to build this DockerFile on different machines

Comment: Also we have faced issue of building docker images from dockerFile on every EC2 instances, because same DockerFile may not always run well on same configuration of machine. Obviously CI way of automating is better than move(or export import). But that i mention as a way that you can use docker command to it.As it might be usefull during development.

Comment: we build on a dedicated docker build machine and tag the image with the appropriate repo tag (e.g. 10.x.x.x/imagename:version) so that we can push to the appropriate repo.  we currently have 3 DTRs setup and have had no issues.  we build and ship all on azure.